# how to get URL / link from google search results and accepted by TMemo

Tags: string, delphi

how to get a lot of URLs from Google.com search and I received it on TMemo without using TWebbrowser. but I do not mean no Source Code HTML / even like this code [eg: `Idhttp.Get ('http://www.google.com/search?q=blah+blah+blah');` ], but only a Text / String URLs from Google search results.

Thx b4.

Comment: Example from superobject https://code.google.com/p/superobject/source/browse/#git%2Fdemos%2Fgooglesearch

Comment: @SirRufo, good point for where to start. Unfortunately, the [`Google Web Search API`](https://developers.google.com/web-search/) is deprecated.

Comment: @TLama The sample fits also to the Custom Search API with some little modifications

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Google's HTML-based website frontend.  It is meant for web browsers and user interactions.  Use Google's [developer APIs](https://developers.google.com) instead, like its [Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) API.

Comment: I mean, I do not expect html script. but make the internet browser that has a simple user interface such as Console Apps / CMD / Terminal, which can only receive text and URL without pictures.

Comment: So what, Utharoz? Google is the only thing you asked about, so why should you expect an answer that covers more? It sounds like you might really want to write a text-mode browser, though. That's *way* too broad a topic to cover in just one question. If that's what you want, consider using [Links](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_(web_browser)).

Comment: google.com is actually just for the example in my question, but in the example I try there is an error on the part: for obj in params ['responseData.results'] do